# c# stop moving picturebox?

Tags: c#, location, picturebox

I have a picture box that moves vertically.
this one makes my picture box which is enemy1 moves automatically:

```
enemy1.Location = new Point(enemy1.Location.X + 0, enemy1.Location.Y + 6);
```

How can I stop the movement? (any code ideas?)
or how can I stop this after bound/intersect/collision?

```
if (fire.Bounds.IntersectsWith(enemy1.Bounds))
{
    //how can I stop enemy1 from moving?
}
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code, preferably as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know what moves the enemy?

My guess is that a timer moves it.

if so, stop the specific timer that moves it:

```
Timer.Stop();
```